# Is there a way to step through Bash Scripts

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

[image]

I work with git-bash in windows. I have found a bash script that I would like to modify on GitHub. I cloned it and opened it in my pycharm editor. There is a plugin https://www.plugin-dev.com/project/bashsupport/#installation which I've added, but from the documentation this does things like syntax highlighting. Is there a way to step through the code line by line, set breakpoints etc. I don't have much shell scripting experience and stepping through the code might speed up my learning .

Comment: You can run one line of your script at a time in the shell...

Comment: Googling "bash debugger", I found http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/. I've never heard of it before so can't say anything for or against.

Comment: As an aside -- generally speaking, `printf` should be used whenever you might otherwise reach for `echo -e` or `echo -n`. See relevant discussion in the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and note that while bash's `echo` is noncompliant *by default*, that's subject to runtime configuration (with compile-time defaults) and not thus always true.

Answer (score 4):

I usually debug using  **-x** flag (short for xtrace or execution trace) is useful to  add execution information [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)).

You can use it by executing:

```
bash -x your-script.sh
```

or adding adding into your script:

```
set -x
```

Comment: Certainly not even remotely the closest thing. A single-step-capable debugger exists; upstream bash has hooks explicitly for its use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you remember the name of the debugger?

Comment: @iconoclast http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ -- mind, I don't personally use it, so don't take that as a recommendation.

Comment: @iconoclast, ...btw, re: the "hooks for its use", see the `DEBUG` trap, and the `extdebug` shell option modifying behavior of same.

Comment: I didn't know this, so thank you! Not upvoting your answer though because I don't think it is really what the OP is looking for